# Select programmatically Kendo grid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I found posts with similar titles but I still cannot resolve my issue. Definitely I am doing something wrong.

In Kendo grid configuration have some function which take context (grid) and read selected row:

```
change: function (e) {
            refresh(this);
        }
```

This is how I configured "change" event.

In function "refresh(grid)" I am getting selected row on following way:

```
    refresh: function (grid) {        
    var selectedRows = grid.select();
    var selectedRow = grid.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
    var id = selectedRow.Id;
}
```

This approach works perfect when I select grid row manually. But when I select row programatically "selectedRow" variable is null.

I am selecting programatically on following way:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
var rows = grid.dataSource.data(); 
var row = rows[rows.length - 1]; 
grid.select(row);
```

As I sad in above, in previous "refresh(grid)" method variable selectedRow will be null.

Does anybody have some opinion about that? Why is it happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the Grid documentation the ["select"](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select) method accepts "string" parameter (selector) or jQuery element. That why if you need to correctly select the row you should modify your current code as follows:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 

//if you are using the "pageable" option of the grid
//you should get the visible rows using the .view() method
var models = grid.dataSource.data();

var model = models[models.length - 1]; 
var lastRowUid = model.uid;

//find the target row element:
var row = grid.table.find("[data-uid=" + lastRowUid + "]");

grid.select(row);
```

Comment: Thanks, only change needed was to change rows[rows.length - 1]; to models[rows.length - 1];